# Executing simple code on android app before closing

Tags: java, android

Hello, I've been trying to integrate airpush in andriod but I've been having some issues.

```
@Override   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

As you can see is the andriod go back code for webview via history.

The problem is that I want execute this code when it has no more history, meaning when the application is about to close.

```
 airpush.startLandingPageAd();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated guys :)..

Comment: put it in the else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider overriding `onPause` method of `Activity` for executing a piece of code before the activity hides.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  airpush.startLandingPageAd();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your code, like this:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack())
        {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
         //Your webview doesn't have any history here and you can close your app here.
         //You can also execute your Airpush code here.
         airpush.startLandingPageAd();
         return true;
        }    
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nope... This makes the application not to close.. It gets stuck.. Can't close the app by pressing back and no code executed...